# How to vertically align `<div>`s side by side without `float`?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Required layout: two boxes should be side by side, but the left one has three vertical boxes inside, while the other is empty. The two boxes should still be vertically aligned at the top.

[image: Mock-up of the required layout.]

But with the code I wrote I’m getting a skewed layout, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5q7ng1xk/2/). Help me fix the issue.

```css
div.left {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
}

div.right {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: checkout flex box css https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for this layout.

```css
.left {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 1 60%;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) for this layout.

```css
.left {
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  background: green;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display: flex` property on the container:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
}
```

In [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5q7ng1xk/2/), you can find your example working like you want.

*And for more information about the flexbox property, you can find a complete guide explaining [here](http://%5Bhere%5D%5B2%5D).*

Answer (score 0):

All is left: align elements to be positioned on top with `vertical-align`

```css
div.left {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
}

div.right {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.left div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Both .left and .right divs need the inline-block display property.

If you want to become a master at layouts look at the display: grid world ;)